# Constant hack attempts for the past 2 days

Tags: wordpress

I notice an increase in my cpu for the last two days so I looked at my access_log and I have been constantly pinged by the ip 46.183.120.20.

```
46.183.120.20 - - [14/Mar/2017:14:11:46 +0000] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 403 221 "-" "-"
```

How do I block this? I have installed failtoban for Wordpress and also added the code below to my .htaccess but they are relentless 2 days now.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 46.183.120.20
```

my error_log is just constantly listing.

```
[Tue Mar 14 14:15:10.466203 2017] [access_compat:error] [pid 30090] [client 46.183.120.20:52003] AH01799: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/example.com/wp-login.php
```

Rotating through to the end of the ip :52003.

Any suggestion on how to stop this attack?

Ok so update I am trying to setup fail2ban i have installed the wp plugin and setup.

```
[wordpress-hard]

enabled = true
filter = wordpress-hard
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
port = http,https
```

If i look at my access_logs i am constantly getting hit with the following pings which is increasing my cpu.

```
POST /administrator/login HTTP/1.1" 404
GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 404
POST /administrator/login HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Trying to find the best way to block these using fail2ban should my logpath be the path to my access_log file?

I am thinking about adding this filter but a bit nervous as i dont have any knowledge of fail2ban

```
failregex = .*:(80|443) <HOST> .*(GET|POST) .*/xmlrpc.php
            .*:(80|443) <HOST> .*(GET|POST) .*/wp-login.php
            .*:(80|443) <HOST> .*(GET|POST) /administrator/index.php
            .*:(80|443) <HOST> .*(GET|POST) /administrator/
            .*:(80|443) <HOST> .*(GET|POST) /administrator/login HTTP
```

When i run a test on the filter this runs for ages.

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/httpd/access_log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/wordpress-hard.conf

Matched time template Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
Matched time template Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
Matched time template Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
Matched time template Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
Matched time template Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
Matched time template Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
Matched time template Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
Matched time template Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
```

Would really appreciate any help or advice on this

Finally, manage to get it work with the following.

```
[block-all]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = block-all
logpath = /var/log/httpd/access_log
maxretry = 10 # number of requests made
findtime = 30 # time scale of those requests
bantime = 600 # ban time 10 minutes
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```

And

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST) .*/administrator
            ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST) .*/administrator/login/
ignoreregex =


restart service fail2ban
```

Not sure if this is good or bad but its working if i run the log file i can see lots of ips are being banned.

```
tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.conf
```

Comment: you need to block at the firewall, not the application level

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to drop this on the firewall itself, since the IP address 46.183.120.20 seems to be in Albania, the best way would be to drop it for a while. (Unless you have admins in Albania).

A simple:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 46.183.120.20 -j DROP
```

Would probably discourage their brute force attempts, and you can add them then again later on.

Alternatively, let your fail2ban script drop them on the ifrewall, not adding it to .htaccess; you don't need your Apache webserver to handle this request that you don't wanna deal with anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a firewall device, you can create a black-list rule to drop packets from this IP.

If you don't have a firewall, you can use the [linux iptables](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_edit_iptables_rules) for that.

Comment: Thanks both i think i am going to use the network ACL's for a VPC in AWS.

Comment: Yep, that should work.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't really work unfortunately because there are tonnes of different ips can anyone suggest another solution?

Comment: @user1503606 You might want to update your question.  The question says the pings are from 46.183.120.20.  If they are using a large number of IPs, you're dealing with a distributed attack, which is handled very differently.

Answer (score 0):

I block things like this using CloudFlare, on the free plan. To make this effective you have to prevent IPs other than CloudFlare and your own IP being able to directly access the server. Since I host in AWS I do this using security groups to block at the hypervisor level, though you can also use NACLs to block at the subnet level. Using an external service reduces your resource consumption.

I also use Nginx to rate access to login pages / scripts, I allow two requests per minute per IP. A distributed attack gets around that, but most simple attacks I've seen from a single IP.